# MySQL table not creating when using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So, I'm trying to create a table via `php`.Below given is the part of code:

```
<?
    # db configurations
    define('DB_HOST',    '127.0.0.1:3306');
    define('DB_USER',    'root');
    define('DB_PASS',    'PWREMOVED');
    define('DB_NAME',    'poll2');

    # db connect
    function dbConnect($close=true){
      global $link;

      if (!$close) {
        mysql_close($link);
        return true;
      }

      $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die('Could not connect to MySQL DB ') . mysql_error();
      if (!mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link))
        return false;
    }

    $sql=CREATE TABLE `voting` (
      `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `fyrir` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `more` text NOT NULL,
      `vote` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );

?>
```

When running this nothing happens to my database.

Comment: run your statement than only it will create table in db.

Comment: please add the code directly in your question

Comment: You are not running your query.

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions your are using are becoming deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP. You should not use them to write new code, use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing the mysql query using `mysql_query()`. The query will get executed/runned only if you use this function. Also you have to enclose the query within quotes.

```
 $sql="CREATE TABLE `voting` (
      `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `fyrir` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `more` text NOT NULL,
      `vote` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )";

mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Still nothing using that. I'm using XAMPP to host the webserver. Am I doing it right by opening it through localhost/PATH to run it or is there some other fancy way to do it?

Comment: You need to run the `dbConnect()` function as well. just defining it will not connect to the DB.

Comment: I did that, nothing still.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the $sql variable, you have to call dbConnection inside the file to open the database connection and then you add: `mysql_query($sql)`. That means:

```
<?php
# db configurations
define('DB_HOST',    'localhost');
define('DB_USER',    'root');
define('DB_PASS',    'PWREMOVED');
define('DB_NAME',    'poll2');

# db connect
function dbConnect(){
    global $link;

    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die('Could not connect to MySQL DB ') . mysql_error();
    if (!mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link))
    return false;
}


$sql="CREATE TABLE `voting` (
      `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `fyrir` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `more` text NOT NULL,
      `vote` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )";
/* call dbConnect to open db connectioin */
dbConnect();
/* Execute the query */
if(!mysql_query($sql))
    die(mysql_error());
else
    echo 'table creation successful';

?>
```

But, why don't you use OOP? It will make things easier.

Answer (score -1):

You are not executing query and query string should be wrapped in `"` Try this code `"` added:

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE `voting` (
      `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `fyrir` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `more` text NOT NULL,
      `vote` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )";
```

Executing mysql query: `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

You forgot to Call `dbConnect` function to connect to mysql: `dbConnect();`

Comment: Still nothing using that. I'm using XAMPP to host the webserver. Am I doing it right by opening it through localhost/PATH to run it or is there some other fancy way to do it?

Comment: @leFluffFluffster Try to use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1:3306` DB_HOST

Comment: Using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1:3306 did not work.

Comment: @leFluffFluffster have you called dbConnect function?

Comment: The full code is inside the pastebin link. I don't have any other codes.